# How to Provide Context from a List of Documents in OpenAI's Chat Completions API?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai

I'm currently using the RAG pattern for answering questions about documents. I'm working with OpenAI's Chat completions API, specifically trying to use a list of documents to provide context to the model. I'm unsure whether to use the SystemMessage or HumanMessage to present this information.

**Objective**:
I want the model to understand the content of the documents and use this as a reference point when generating responses to user queries.

**Current Approach:**

I've tried two approaches(These are simplified examples):

1. Using **SystemMessage** to set a general context:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You have access to a set of documents about ancient Egyptian artifacts. <List of documents>"},
    {"role": "human", "content": "Tell me about the significance of the Ankh symbol."}
  ]
}
```

2. Embedding the document content directly into a **HumanMessage**:

```
{
    "messages": [
      {"role": "system", "content": "You have access to a set of documents about ancient Egyptian artifacts."},
      {"role": "human", "content": "According to: <List of documents>, the Ankh symbol was used in many rituals. Can you expand on this?"}
    ]
  }
```

**Questions**:

1. Which of these approaches is more effective in providing context to
   the model?
2. Is there a better way to ensure that the model effectively
   understands and uses the document content as context?
3. Are there limitations in terms of the amount of context or document
   size I should be aware of?

Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK usually the system message is set only once before the chat begins, and it is used to guide the model to answer in a specific way. In a RAG scenario you could set the system message to specify that the chat model will receive queries and sets of documents to get the information from, but the actual documents would be fed to model inside each human message, since you could get different sets of documents from each massage through your retriever.

Regarding the amount of context, you can find each model context windows [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5)

Usually it's better to not use the full context window for cost reasons and also because an LLM tends to perform better when the context is shorter, so sending too much information could make your output worse.

Comment: Well, this is not true. Each query of the LLM is a standalone individual prompt unrelated to all other queries in the chat completion. It is the developer's responsibility to chain the previous queries and answers into a logical and valid prompt that contains the conversion "history".
Therefore, the system message should be part of each prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be various, depending on the actual scenario. Therefore, I would answer your question in the following aspects:

1. In term of prompt injection attacks > https://blog.langchain.dev/chat-models/

> a commonly known type of attack against LLM applications is prompt injection attacks, where the end user directs the application to do something it wasn’t intended to do. By adding this structure into the prompt now, in theory, end applications could put all their application instructions in the “system” messages, all end user input in the “user” messages, and then the model could be trained to always “obey” system messages, despite what the user messages may tell it.

and

> Chat Message
>
> - HumanMessage: a message sent from the perspective of the human
> - AIMessage: a message sent from the perspective of the AI the human  interacting with
> - SystemMessage: a message setting the objectives the AI should follow
> - ChatMessage: a message allowing for arbitrary setting of role

You *may* define a limit in `SystemMessage`. Then your 1st snippet of code is preferred.

Also find this reference > https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/chat/

2. According to OpenAI's GPT best practices > https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt-best-practices/strategy-write-clear-instructions

Under "Tactic: Use delimiters to clearly indicate distinct parts of the input", USER can insert article(s) in XML, which is similar to your 2nd sample.

3. If your `list_of_documents` is extensive, you *may* want to consider `embedding` it into a VectorStore for `similarity_search` together with `chat` with OpenAI, for `chain` optimization and performance.

You can utilize `RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter` function to split the documents with `chunk_size` which can be adjusted based on the requirements of different models.